# Delegate jquery ui sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

In my page load dynamically photos with ajax.
For elements and functions I'm trying to use event delegation.
Unfortunately for UI sortable I was forced to use the function referencing

HTML dinamically generated from id

```
<div class="row sortable">
    <div class="col-md-2 thumb" id="photo_1">
        <span class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img_1.jpg" alt="" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="photo[]" value="1" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 thumb" id="photo_2">
        <span class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img_2.jpg" alt="" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="photo[]" value="2" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 thumb" id="photo_3">
        <span class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img_3.jpg" alt="" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="photo[]" value="3" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY JS

```
var id = "something";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: photo.php,
    data: { id : id },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#photo-container').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
        callSortable(); // Function referencing
    }
});

// DELEGATE
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="photo[]"]', function() {
    // do something
});

function callSortable() {
    $('.sortable').sortable({
        items       : 'div:not(.unsortable)',
        delay       : 150,
        revert      : true,
        scroll      : false,
        update: function(e, ui) {
            //save position
        }
    });
}
```

How could I do to use the event delegation with UI sortable in my scenario?
Thank You

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What do you mean by: *"use the event delegation with UI sortable"* ?

Comment: I'd like to know how to use the event delegation (like the checkbox) for sortable in place of function referencing, if this is possible

Comment: Can you simply say what is the problem with your current code and expected behaviour? I really have no idea what event delegation you mean. Seems to me like XY problem.

Comment: I'd have not use the function refencing (callSortable) to use ui sortable but use event delegation, if this is possible. I hope I was clear

Comment: I **do** understand your intention. What I **do not** understand is what is that for? What *event* you want to delegate (name it)? What makes you think that you need for the *event delegation*? What is the actual problem with your app (because I believe *event delegation* is your attempt to fix some problem?). Post the actual problem, not the solution you think will work. See: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'd like to know if is possibile to delegate sortable event, like click, change, etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JQuery UI's Sortable Widget has the `sortupdate` [event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update), try delegating like this:

```
$(document).on('sortupdate', '.sortable', function () {
    console.log("Sorting updated");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2fzLo6gr/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!